# Passing Matrix as pointer to function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, matrix

In my project I've these files:

```
functions.h
functions.cc
main.cc
```

I'm trying to pass Matrix to functions as pointers in this way:

**main.cc**

```
// Size -> const short Size = 10;
int mtr1[Size][Size];
matrix_insert((int *)mtr1);
```

**functions.h**

```
void matrix_insert(int *mtr);
```

**functions.cc**

```
void matrix_insert(int *mtr) {
  short i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
      std::cin >> *(mtr + i * Size + j);
    }
  }
}
```

This is actually working but I don't like this way...
Is there a better method?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Is possible to emulate matrix with vector?

Comment: This looks rather C-ish. Use a matrix class instead.

Comment: Yes I know I could do this with classes but it's an homework for school.

Comment: In C, array size is compile time thing, and array syntax is just getting compiler do the multiplication. If you want something fancier than in the first answer, you should make matrix a struct with row and column counts and pointer to data. In C++ you can add helper methods inside the struct, in plain C they have to be functions taking the struct or pointer to struct as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use C arrays, then you can do it as follows:

**main.cc**

```
int mtr1[Size][Size];
matrix_insert(mtr1);
```

**functions.h**

```
const short Size = 10;
void matrix_insert(int mtr[Size][Size]);
```

**functions.cc**

```
void matrix_insert(int mtr[Size][Size]) {
  short i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
      std::cin >> mtr[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Working version: http://ideone.com/1ik7T9

Comment: But by this way I create another matrix (other than the one from main.cc), am I wrong?

Comment: @Edoardo: you are wrong. The above function declaration is *exactly the same as* `void matrix_insert(int (*mtr)[Size]);`, which means 'a function that receives a pointer to an array of arrays of size `Size` `int`s and returns `void`'.

Comment: @Edoardo In C and C++ arrays are passed as pointers, so no copying takes place.

Comment: Can I omit the first size? example: int mtr[][Size]

Comment: @Edoardo: Yes. `T p[][n]`, `T (*p)[n]` and `T p[m][n]` are all equivalent (as function parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix class like this one:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using templates:

```
template<int Size>
void matrix_insert(int (&mtr)[Size][Size])
{
    short i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            std::cin >> mtr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```